# How to get all the visited url lists from any browser programmatically using c# in .Net 2.0 framework

Tags: c#

I have to track the lists of all the visited urls from any browser like Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera etc.

To get the all opened tabs in the Internet Explorer, I have used the below codes :

```
SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
string filename;
ArrayList windows = new ArrayList();
foreach (SHDocVw.WebBrowser ie in shellWindows)
{
    filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).ToLower();
    if (filename.Equals("iexplore"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IE Url for '" + ie.LocationName + "' is " + (ie.LocationURL));
    }
}
```

But my question is that how can I get this same all the opened tabs description from  other browser?

I have found the below code to get the only one tab which is open in the browser.

using DDE to get the current tab.

```
private string GetBrowserURL(string browser) 
{
    try {
        DdeClient dde = new DdeClient(browser, "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
        dde.Connect();
        string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
        string[] text = url.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" },  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        dde.Disconnect();
        return text[0].Substring(1);
    } 
    catch {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have checked WinPCap, SharpPcap, Pcap but could not get the right solutions to solve the issue.

I need a source code using c# which will be running successfully in .Net 2.0 framework to get the all visited urls lists from all the browser.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Use a proxy server that does logging if you want to spy on your users. Not all browsers offer a "browse my history" API ([IE does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms774939(v=vs.85).aspx)), so you'll have to code it for each browser and keep it updated when the implementation changes.

Comment: Sir, There are more than one machine to get the information. This solutions will not be possiable in this case.  Thanks

Comment: Of course you can. Use a company-wide proxy so all HTTP traffic travels over that machine. You can then do with that what you want. If that isn't what you need, explain what you are trying to do or what specifically you need help with and what you have tried.

Comment: Sir, right now we do not want to implement proxy server, rather we want to get the result using core C# coding in .Net framework 2.0

Comment: Please don't call me sir. I explained how you can obtain the history for each browser: by implementing it yourself. You can search the web or this site for terms like "C# read {browsername} history" and off you go.

Comment: I have searched through this criteria but don't get the solution to fetch all visited url lists. Now, I want to know, is it possiable to get the same using winpcap, Pcap, SharpPcap ? If so, please help me regarding this.

Comment: It is impossible that you couldn't find anything. That you can't get it to work is something else. It is possible using pcap, but you don't want to do that. You'll then also miss https urls.